# Changing Data Protection Type in existing iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements, apple-developer

We have an iOS app which is currently published in the App Store. We have set the Data Protection as `NSFileProtectionComplete` in Xcode AppName.entitlements and also in the App ID settings in the developer account.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.default-data-protection</key>
<string>NSFileProtectionComplete</string>
```

[image: Developer Account]

Now we are planning to change the Data Protection to `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication` since we are unable to read NSUserDefaults data when the device is in locked state due to `NSFileProtectionComplete` Data protection restrictions. I can see an option in the Developer account to update the Data Protection in the App ID settings. I have couple of questions regarding this change,

- if i update the settings, will this effect the app in the App Store?
- will this change effect the existing profiles and
  certificates?
- after making the changes, will the Data Protection mechanism change will be applicable for all existing files or it will only effect the newly created files after this change.

We have very less information regarding changing the Data Protection mechanism. Any information will be really helpful. After iOS 15 update i can see lot of developers were facing some issue while they are trying to fetch the data in the background if they are using `NSFileProtectionComplete` and the only solution i found is changing the Data Protection mechanism. This might help other developers as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Q. if i update the settings, will this effect the app in the App Store?**

A. No impact to App Store/current apps out in production

**Q. will this change effect the existing profiles and certificates?**

A. Yep, It'll invalidate all profiles associated with this bundle id

**Q. after making the changes, will the Data Protection mechanism change will be applicable for all existing files or it will only effect the newly created files after this change.**

A. A few sources I've read indicate that all existing files will remain as-is (meaning you will need to migrate the protection level manually for them). The change will only affect new files created. See - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666982